# MYSQL database resets after every update

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net

Every time I update one click application on clients computer, the MYSQL database automatically resets itself. How do I retain the database?
P.S: I'm new to the world of programming.

Comment: what does "resets itself" mean in the world you come from?  Starts with a new, empty DB?

Comment: yes, it starts with a new, empty DB and all the previous records are lost.